# action bar is hiding onclick on last edittext,i cannot use scrollview due to multiple layouts

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build a form for sign up which includes 10 `edittexts`, which should be in certain format I cannot change the format ...and even I am not able to use the scroll view

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true",
```

scrolling behaviour of layout and scroll views for layouts in the activity but it keeps on hiding on the click on the last edit text.

My xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="#e7ebe8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/lastNameSignUpEditText"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="0"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/genderSignUpEditText"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/genderSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:inputType="text" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateOfBirthSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobileNumberSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:inputType="number" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otpMobileNumberSignUpPageTextView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="By tapping CONFIRM you agree to the"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Terms and Conditions"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor=" #FF0000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButtonSignUpPage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="#e7ebe8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/lastNameSignUpEditText"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="0"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/genderSignUpEditText"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/genderSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:inputType="text" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateOfBirthSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobileNumberSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:inputType="number" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otpMobileNumberSignUpPageTextView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="By tapping CONFIRM you agree to the"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Terms and Conditions"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor=" #FF0000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButtonSignUpPage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scrollview` instead of `relativelayout`; please see my below code, I have updated it.

**Imp:-** Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity tag in android manifest xml like below.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

**Xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="#e7ebe8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/lastNameSignUpEditText"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastNameSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="0"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/genderSignUpEditText"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/genderSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:inputType="text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateOfBirthSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailSignUpEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otpEmailSignUpPageTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordSignUpEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_text_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="By tapping CONFIRM you agree to the"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Terms and Conditions"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor=" #FF0000"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButtonSignUpPage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```